# Unexpected reserved word 'import' when using babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Using Babel in my NodeJSv4.1.1 code.

Got the require hook in:

```
require("babel-core/register");

$appRoot = __dirname;

module.exports = require("./lib/controllers/app");
```

In a subsequently lodaded `.js` file I am doing:

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
```

However this is generating the following error in the CLI:

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at loader (/Users/*/Documents/Web/*/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/*/Documents/Web/*/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at module.exports (index.js:9:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:102:39)
```

Comment: what version of Babel?

Comment: `"babel-core": "^6.1.21"`

Comment: have you included any Babel plugins or presets?

Comment: nope, i tried es2015preset but this broke my app as well, i got an issue where it was saying the following was undefined: `$passport = require('passport');`

Comment: Is this on line 1? The error is being reported by the babel module.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Comment: @Rob with the es2015 preset, if you change `$passport = require('passport');` to `var $passport = require('passport');`, do you still see that error?

Comment: This is a common error when running plain Node, which means you're likely seeing this because Babel isn't actually running. I would recommend switching over the the `babel-register` module as suggested by [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) since you're using Babel 6. Then make sure the file in question isn't getting ignored. See @pherris' comment below

Comment: Also make sure you have correct `.babelrc`. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: @ian - the stack dump includes this line: `at loader (/Users/*/Documents/Web/*/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)` which sure sounds like `babel-register` is being used to me...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't using the right presets. As of babel 6, the core babel loader no longer includes the expected ES6 transforms by default (it's now a generic code transformer platform), instead you must use a preset:

```
require('babel-register')({
        "presets": ["es2015"]
});
```

You will also need to install the preset package:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: where does this code belong? in a webpack config? in a babelconfig? in the code that I'm running?

Comment: @omouse you'd usually put this into whatever your main entrypoint is, typically index.js at the top level, before requiring the rest of your code

Comment: As a little addition, I had to `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` since it didn't come by default with babel-register.  But this answer worked for me!

Comment: I tried all that is mentioned here, but still I get this error. Very annoying. I got the top require("babel-core/register"); upgraded node/npm to 4.4/3.8.1. Have a file .babelrc with { "presets": ["es2015"] }. Installed babel-core, babel-register, babel-preset-2015. My node file has just the require above and import asap from "asap"; right under...

Comment: @Fractalf: the transpiler from babel-register does not apply to the file in which it is required, so you cannot use `import` in the same file. You must instead require another file which can then use full es2015 semantics

Comment: @ArkadiyKukarkin: thanks, so I tried to just require the es6 module and use babel-core in only that module, but then there is the same error just complaining about export. I got it all working with babel-node, and then just building it, but man how hard is this for a first time user! Very bad documentation for those who didn't touch babel yet :(

Comment: Finally found something that made this work: https://leanpub.com/setting-up-es6/read#sec_nodejs-babel-dynamic  https://github.com/rauschma/node-babel-dynamic-demo

Comment: it's working after i place on very top of line on my app file root, thanks

Comment: use `babel-preset-env` it covers babel-preset-2015-17 and its going to recommend it.

Comment: I created a .babelrc in the root directory of the project and added `{
 "presets": ["es2015"]
}` to it

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this file is not being transpiled. Is this subsequently loaded `.js` file in the node_modules directory? If so, you need to:

```
require("babel-core/register")({
  // This will override `node_modules` ignoring - you can alternatively pass
  // an array of strings to be explicitly matched or a regex / glob
  ignore: false
});
```

> By default all requires to node_modules will be ignored. You can override this by passing an ignore regex

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/

Comment: I have subsequent requires which the require other things does this work okay w/ babel?

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the problem when trying to run tests via mocha, and I solved it by putting this in my package.json file:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
},
```

I'm not completely clear on how this works. I'm running tests like this:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive
```

Eventually, this will all make sense I suppose.