# Does Jest support ES6 import/export?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, babel-jest

If I use `import/export` from ES6 then all my Jest tests fail with error:

> Unexpected reserved word

I convert my object under test to use old school [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) syntax and suddenly my tests pass. Or, take an even simpler test case:

```
   var Validation = require('../src/components/validation/validation'); // PASS
   //import * as Validation from '../src/components/validation/validation' // FAIL
```

Same error. Obviously there's a problem with import/export here. It's not practical for me to rewrite my code using ES5 syntax just to make my test framework happy.

I have babel-jest. I tried various [suggestions](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest/issues/22) from GitHub issues.  It is no go so far.

#### File *package.json*

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest"
  },
      "jest": {
        "testPathDirs": [
          "__tests__"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/"
        ],
        "testFileExtensions": ["es6", "js"],
        "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "es6"]
      },
```

#### File *babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710319/unexpected-reserved-word-import-when-using-babel) help at all?

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - Possibly.  I'm not sure if/how the solution applies to babel-jest

Comment: it's a matter of specifying something like  "presets": ["es2015"] in a package.json or a .babelrc.  you are using babel, after all.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - In that case the solution does not work.  I already have a babelrc containing es2015, react presets.  Standard transpilation works, inside of gulp.  It's just the Jest framework that can't handle it.

Comment: it worked for someone [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest/issues/49) by installing babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-react packages.  sorry if I'm not being much help--haven't had this issue.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - I agree that the solution works in general.  I had to add these values to get Babel to transpile correctly.  I mean to say that the solution does not fix the issue at hand.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Here's the [GitHub issue tracking ES6 module support in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4842#issuecomment-401877985).

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, if possible, reconsider the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This question is from 5 years ago and yet jest's support for ES modules is experimental.

Comment: I updated the answer with a newer and simpler method

Answer (score 198, accepted):

**[Dec 2023 UPDATE]**

Now you can support ES6 and ESM (ECMAScript modules) **natively**.

It's a prerequisite to set `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`.

**Here are the steps:**

**Step 1:** Prevent Jest from trying to transform ESM code to CommonJS, updating your Jest config (`package.json` example below) with:

```json
"jest": {
    ...
    "transform": {}
}
```

**Step 2:** To be able to parse ES modules without an external transformer (e.g., babel), start Node with the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag. This can be done by changing how Jest is started by the npm "test" script (again inside `package.json`):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

And that's it. :)

You can even uninstall your transformer packages if you were using them just for the tests.

---

**[OUTDATED answer, just for historic purposes]**

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656707/279712) to another question, this can be simpler:

The only requirement is to configure your `test` environment to Babel, and add the ECMAScript 6 transform plugin:

---

**Step 1:**

Add your `test` environment to `.babelrc` in the root of your project:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Install the ECMAScript 6 transform plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```

---

**And that's it.** Jest will enable compilation from ECMAScript modules to [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) automatically, without having to inform additional options to your `jest` property inside `package.json`.

Comment: If you don't want to pollute your project with `.babelrc`, you can add the `env` key above under a `babel` key in `package.json`.

Comment: Good hint! Thanks @DanDascalescu !

Comment: Actually, funny coincidence: I've *just* worked around [this Jest bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8238) the day before by moving the `babel` key out of `package.json` into `babel.config.js`. The bug only affects running transforms on files imported from the parent directory of the project.

Comment: I believe the more recent `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` replaces `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

Comment: I will try that, @Albizia ! And, if it works, I will update the answer. Thanks for the note!

Comment: This has been a great answer.  However it appears that things have changed in the years since.  So I'm moving the answer to the newly supported answer comment.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey sure! If you already tested the new approach, and Babel isn't needed anymore, this is good news and it's important to update the community about the updated approach. :)

Comment: having babel config for jest in package.json is not working for me. is it because my jest config is not in package.json?

Comment: This worked really well for me!  Thank you so much! 
Here's hoping to have a stable support for ESM in jest soon!

Comment: I updated the answer with a newer and simpler method

Comment: @PauloCoghi In your 2023 update you mention updating the package.json with

"jest": {
    "transform": {}
}

Do you mean the jest.config.js file?

Comment: @JesseYentsch You can configure Jest through two ways: `package.json` or `jest.config.js`. In my example, I was considering the first way, but you can simply add the `"transform": {}` property inside `jest.config.js` if you prefer to use it instead.

Comment: Still required to add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, otherwise Jest throws `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error.

Comment: Correct. I will update the answer

Answer (score 123):

## UPDATE 2020 - native support of ECMAScript modules (ESM)

---

According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430), there is native support of ESM from `jest@25.4.0`. So you won't have to use babel anymore. At the time of writing this answer (05/2020), to activate that you need to do three simple things:

- Make sure you don't transform away `import` statements by setting `transform: {}` in config file
- Run `node@^12.16.0 || >=13.2.0` with `--experimental-vm-modules` flag
- Run your test with `jest-environment-node` or `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen`.

So your Jest configuration file should contain at least this:

```
export default {
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node',
    transform: {}
    ...
};
```

And to set `--experimental-vm-modules` flag, you will have to run Jest as follows:

```
node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

Also note in the Github issue that this approach does not yet support the `jest` object. So you may need to import it manually:

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'
```

(*I hope this will change in the future*)

Comment: What is the 'jest-environment-node' and how does it differ from an environment 'node'?

Comment: it's a test environment that will be used for testing. It's `jsdom` by default. You can find more information here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string

Comment: I've been running into `Maximum call stack size exceeded` (`internal/vm/module.js:315 const module = await linker(identifier, this);`) with this method. Is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: `NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' jest` is a bit cleaner to run jest

Comment: As an important note, native support does **not** support mocking as of yet

Comment: 4th thing to do to make this work: package.json should contain `"type": "module"` for Node to detect files as ESM, see https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system

Comment: I only needed `NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' jest` on node `v14.6.1` and jest `v26.6.3`. No config.

Comment: I also had to add `"type": "modules"` to the root of my `package.json`. See more in the [Jest docs about ES modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).

Comment: FYI, using ESM in `testEnvironment` was only added in 27.0.0: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11232

Comment: I tried this modern solution locally on my repo but doesn't work. Still have the issue. Open to anyone who can assist with it - minimal reproducible repo included: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433797/turborepo-jest-unable-to-transpile-external-esm-package

Answer (score 42):

For an updated configuration, I'm using https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Select JEST and be happy:

As a reference, the current configuration:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

In your *package.json* file, make the following changes:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Install babel preset:

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

Create a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Run your tests:

```
npm run test
```

Comment: Worked for me! The babel docs have been updated to specify .ts files too in the regex.
Didn't need any other dependency for typescript like ts-jest. I did need @babel/preset-typescript. Added it to the list of presets in the .babelrc file.

Comment: This is basically the correct answer. Here is another good reference page from jest's own docs https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel

Comment: thanks this worked for me. As of now, you do **not** need to add the `transform` to your `package.json`. It is now default.

Comment: Worked for me, but I still need the `transform` settings. I have them in `jest.config.js`: `"transform": {"^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"}`

Comment: it worked, thank you.


Question, is this better than using
```
node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest
```

I suppose yes, but if someone can explain a little bit more it is welcome.


Apart from that i still have to understand more about the .babelrc, and transform section, why do we need to include this new package? is this not included in jest by default ? i have to look into it.

Answer (score 9):

In `package.json`, kindly set like this one: `"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest"`

Should be good!

Comment: Nope! won't do it! Mocks will not work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There are some nuances to getting `jest` to work and even on Windows vs Mac sometimes issues. NS what you are trying to do exactly, but here is [a template](https://github.com/manavm1990/node-starter) repo that I use for Node stuff that has a fully working `jest` (using `nodemon`). It includes other stuff that you may or may not want, but you can at least use as a guide?

Comment: I followed this answer instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224329/985942 basically use babel to transform everything back to commonjs

Comment: Right. That's what that repo ends up doing. 

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of adding stage-0 to your .babelrc file. Here is an example:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Comment: PS: don't forget to install the stage-0 preset through npm

Comment: Don’t ever use `stage-0` or any `stage-*` in production. This answer is bad practice. Use `preset-env`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue.

These are what I did:

`yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

Make file *jest.config.js* in *rootDir.*

```js
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "json"],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1'
    },
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)', '<rootDir>/(tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))'
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
};
```

Then make file *babal.config.js* in *rootDir*.

Go like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As for today, with node 16 and jest 29 I only needed to define a test script as below:

`package.json`

```
"type": "module",
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' jest ."
  },
```

Comment: I just tried this in a new project, and it doesn't work

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I setup jest, typescript and ES Modules for my project.

`jest.config.js`

```
/**
 * @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} 
 * To configure ESM support, see: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support
 * 
 **/
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            useESM: true
        }
    },
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.ts'],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
       // "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
    }
}
```

`package.json` scripts and devDependencies

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/server.js\"",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^27.4.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "supertest": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3"
  }
```

`__tests__/setup.ts`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';


dotenv.config({
    path: './.env.test'
});
```

Comment: And how would you specify ESM modules if it were JS instead of TS?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: I mean would this work if using JS instead of TS? because I tried Jest with JS code with ES6 modules and Jest doesn't even recognize the import keyword and complains about an unknown token.

Comment: @Petruza of course Jest recognizes the import keyword. You just have to use experimental-vm-modules parameter. Btw you want to make sure that jest targets the build output  that is in javascript and not the typescript that has not yet been built. Your tests can be written in javascript although the source code is in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

all is explained in the jest docs: [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel)

1.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

2. in file: babel.config.js

   ```
   module.exports = {
     presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To solve you need to add on *package.json*

```
"type": "module",
```

**And** set *test* property on *package.json* to

```
"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest"
```

It works for me on node version v16.19.0.
Reference - [kevinhooke](https://www.kevinhooke.com/2022/12/11/node16-and-jest-with-es6-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing `babel-jest` (which comes with Jest by default now) be sure to install `regenerator-runtime`.

Comment: If I configured jest with a babel config like this `{presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]]};` then regenerator runtime was not needed (without the node:'current' part it did warn about this). See https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel

Answer (score 0):

To add support for React and react-testing-library it may be useful to eject **CreateReactApp** and take all needed Jest configuration from the `package.json`. It is ready to use with another bundler, Rollup in my case.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, you'll need to configure Jest to handle ES6 modules properly. You can do this by using Babel to transpile your code so that Node.js can understand the ES6 syntax.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-jest
```

.babelrc

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
    clearMocks: true,
    roots: ['./test'],
    testMatch: ['**/*.test.js'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^src/(.*)$': './src/$1',
        '^test/(.*)$': './test/$1',
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```