# Jest import of plain javascript results in unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Firstly: as far as I can tell, this is not a duplicate. The other questions with similar problems are all slightly different, e.g. use a transformation like babel or have problems with transitive imports. In my case I have no transformation, I have one test file and one file imported file that will be tested. I just started using jest and use the default setting, so there is no configuration file to post.

When I try to run my tests I get the error message:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

The tested file:

```
export function showTooltip(x, y, content) {
    const infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
    infoElement.style.left = `${x}px`;
    infoElement.style.top = `${y}px`;
    infoElement.style.display = 'block';
    infoElement.innerText = createTooltipText(content);
}

function createTooltipText(object) {
    return Object.keys(object)
        .filter(key => key != 'id')
        .map(key => `${key} : ${object[key]}`)
        .join('\n');
}

export function hideTooltip() {
    const infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
    infoElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The test:

```
import {showTooltip, hideTooltip} from '../../../src/public/javascripts/tooltip.js';

const TOOLTIP_DUMMY = {
    style: {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        display: '',
        innerText: ''
    }
};

test('showTooltip accesses the element with the id \'info\'', () => {
    const getElementByIdMock = jest.fn(() => TOOLTIP_DUMMY);
    document.getElementById = getElementByIdMock;
    showTooltip(0, 0, {});

    expect(getElementByIdMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('info');
});

test('hideTooltip accesses the element with the id \'info\'', () => {
    const getElementByIdMock = jest.fn(() => TOOLTIP_DUMMY);
    document.getElementById = getElementByIdMock;
    hideTooltip();

    expect(getElementByIdMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('info');
});
```

As you can see I am using plain javascript so I am not sure what to do here. The error message gives further hints about Babel which does not really apply to my case.

Sidenote: My test might be flawed. I am currently trying to figure out how to use mocks to avoid interaction with the document and I am not sure if that is the way. However this is not the point of this question as it should not affect the ability of the tests to run, but I am very open for suggestions.

**EDIT**: Why this is not a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43366382/5909613): It kind of is, but I feel that question and the accepted answer were not really helpful for me and hopefully someone will profit from this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest es6 modules: unexpected module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366382/jest-es6-modules-unexpected-module-import)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to my problem:

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43368563/5909613), you need to use Babel. This can be done as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/hliyan/c50bfe7d3a9d83216872d9b6271def8b), but I used [`@babel/env-preset`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) as it is suggested on the Babel website.
This left me with the problem that jest internally uses `babel-core@6.26.3`, but at least babel 7 was required. This problem is described [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6913). I used the temporary fix of manually copying and overwriting `babel-core` from my node-modules directory to the node-modules directories of `jest-config` and `jest-runtime`. This dirty fix is also described in the previous link.

I have yet to find a clean solution, but at least this works.

Comment: You can try to use Create React App and eject it, if you need. They solved all this package trickery. Life is too short for manual configuration. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @DimaVishnyakov I have to admit I am not very familiar with the tools of the javascript world, so could you elaborate what you mean by "using and ejecting it"?

Comment: `npx create-react-app app-name` downloads and configures modern React application framwerok from Facebook. Create-react-app (CRA) has everything to start development (including Jest and eslint), and requires zero configuration. Just `yarn start` and code. Eventually you may need more precise control over your app config. To achieve that you can `yarn eject` which exposes internal configuration options. 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Use `global.document.getElementById = getElementByIdMock;` In some configurations Jest doesn't have access to document object directly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I appreciate it a lot! However I am not sure if this should be posted as an answer or a comment as it not answers the main question. Still a +1, because it is actually helpful.