# Test ES6 modules with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

How to test ES6 modules with Jest.

---

Example:

**sum.js**

```js
const sum = function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

export default sum;
```

**sum.test.js**

```js
import sum from './sum';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**[Dec 2023 UPDATE]**

Now you can support ES6 and ESM (ECMAScript modules) **natively**:

**Step 1:** Prevent Jest from trying to transform ESM code to CommonJS, updating your Jest config (`package.json` example below) with:

```json
"jest": {
    "transform": {}
}
```

**Step 2:** To be able to parse ES modules without an external transformer (e.g., babel), start Node with the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag. This can be done by changing how Jest is started by the npm "test" script (again inside `package.json`):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

And that's it. :)

You can even uninstall your transformer packages if you were using them just for the tests.

---

**[OUTDATED answer, just for historic purposes]**

The only requirement is to config your `test` environment to Babel, and add the es2015 transform plugin:

---

**Step 1:**

Add your `test` environment to `.babelrc` in the root of your project:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Install the es2015 transform plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```

---

**And that's it.** Jest will enable compilation from ES modules to CommonJS automatically, without having to inform additional options to your `jest` property inside `package.json`.

Comment: this answer may be outdated, GarouDan's answer is the [officially suggested solution](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel)

Comment: GarouDan's answer is not the officially suggested solution for ES6 modules but, instead, for Typescript scenarios. They are not the same thing.

Comment: While GarouDan's solution includes typescript support, following the link I provided shows the well documented Jest ES6 implementation without typescript, from which GarouDan's solution is derived. The changes needed to support typescript are negligible, but I agree it is not relevent to the question.

Comment: @chantey Now the answer is updated again, with a newer and simpler method.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions above didn't work for me. I was able to solve with this:

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ],
};
```

where I'm using **typescript**.

[Reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel).