# jest encountered an unexpected token-looks like not able to transform jsx elements

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have originally started with react-scripts test but Console.log is not behaving properly(it print messages sometimes) so i decided to move on to jest (console.log works with jest,also jest can support more than react-script test).

Now,I am getting below  error.

FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
```

App.test.js: Unexpected token (11:20)

```
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
```

> ```
>   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
>                      ^
>    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
> });
> ```

Environment
this application is on windows 10 pro

node              v10.9.0
 npm               6.2.0

I have followed [Does Jest support ES6 import/export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export)
 but it throws same error,what is stage 0 and why stage 0 is dangerous?

package.json file
    enter code here

```
{
"name": "my-ui",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.8"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"build-dev": "dotenv -e .env.development react-scripts build",
"test": "jest",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
],
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"dotenv-cli": "^1.4.0",
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"jsx-to-string": "^1.4.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
},
".babelrc": {
"presets": [
"es2015",
"react"
]
}
}
```

I have two test case- for this
one of them is showing me expected behavious and other is throwing above error.

I have App.test.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

//below test case throws above error.
it('renders without crashing', () => {
const div = document.createElement('div');
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});

//below should print output - working correctly.
it('it is printing', () => {
console.log('Hellllooo');
expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I addition, In app.js I am switching between modules,for example i have routes defined, how should I mock it or bypass

Comment: curruntly I am not able to start my application- using npm start,if i switch jest with react-script test and remove babel-dependency then it works.

Comment: this is resolved with - following link.https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/unit-testing-react-components-jest-or-enzyme-du1087lh8  make sure to have following - "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/react",
      "@babel/env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }