# Jest import statement: 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of null'

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, phaser-framework

I type:

```
npm test
```

and I get:

[image]

It's interesting to note that the import statement works inside the BootScene.test.js file but it doesn't work in the imported file.

I focused on the import statement not working under JEst. So I thought maybe it has something to do with Ecma Script version jest uses. So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export) solution but the error persists.

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/space-shooter-game/tree/setup-project) is the repo/branch of this question.

When I type `npm start`. Everything flows swiftly and with no errors.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the import itself since the actual error is inside the `phaser` module (implying it was in fact imported), as you can see from the call stack. Try googling `phaser Cannot set property fillStyle of null` and you'll find several GitHub issues pointing towards a solution of installing `canvas-prebuilt` and/or installing and requiring `jest-canvas-mock` before your other imports.

Comment: Also check out [this article](https://medium.com/@Tnodes/setting-up-jest-with-react-and-phaser-422b174ec87e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by following [this](https://medium.com/@Tnodes/setting-up-jest-with-react-and-phaser-422b174ec87e) instructions.

[image]

Thanks CherryDt.

Comment: Self-answers are welcome on SO but consider providing all necessary information in the post itself. It becomes useless if a link becomes unavailable - and this is very possible for this link because Medium has a paywall.

Comment: In addition, CherryDt also appears to have solved this, so in the future I would recommend asking the person that solved your issue via comments to submit an answer that you can mark as the answer.

Answer (score 24):

The error occurs because jestdom is not able add canvas, which we need to do. For me this happened because I was using lottiefiles for the application.

Here is how I fixed it for my react application.

Install jest-canvas-mock as below .

```
 npm i jest-canvas-mock
```

Then go to setup file like *setup-tests.js* and import jest-canvas as below .

```
import "jest-canvas-mock";
```

Now run test, you should not get errors any more.

Comment: Just for clarity, if you are defining Jest in package.json, then do something like this in package.json.
  "setupFiles": [
      "../setupTests.ts",
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ],

Answer (score 2):

Installing npm i jest-canvas-mock
and Importing import "jest-canvas-mock" in set-up file; works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).