# 'ReferenceError: jest is not defined' when running unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm in the early stages of a new app that so far just uses vanilla JS. I'm trying to use ES6 modules for my Jest unit tests, so I followed the [2020 updated instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652773) on making this possible.

However, after following those instructions, I get the error `ReferenceError: jest is not defined` when running my unit test.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node",
    "transform": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-environment-node": "^26.6.2",
    "open": "^7.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Below is my test file. The error occurs due to the jest.fn call:

```
import { getTotalNumPeople } from "./app.js";


test("Get total number of people", async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve({count: 15})
        })
    )
    
    expect(await getTotalNumPeople()).toBe(15);
});
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm confident that the issue has to do with the steps I followed to support ES6 modules. Prior to these changes, my test ran fine when I simply pasted the `getTotalNumPeople` function in my test file.

If I comment out mocking my function, I then get a ReferenceError about fetch not being defined (since `getTotalNumPeople` uses fetch). So it's not just `jest` that's not defined.

I notice that if I do not specify `jest-environment-node` as my test environment, the error changes to `ReferenceError: global is not defined` due to referring to `global.fetch` in my test. Just thought I'd note that in case that helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I was expecting your package.json to have a script like this: `"test": "jest"` so jest runs as a cli. More here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started

Comment: @stealththeninja I did have that script originally. But after following the instructions for enabling ES6 modules with Jest, I replaced that script with `"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It looks like you didn’t import jest, so you have to just add this line to the top of the file:

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'
```

For more details, see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430#issuecomment-616232029) on native support for ES6 modules in Jest.

Comment: This gives me a runtime error: `Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment`

Comment: @SlavaFominII: Yup! I am getting same error! Is there any fix for the same

Comment: this is not the full solution as getting errors for Do not import @jest/globals`

Comment: Can you provide code so i can check?

Comment: should not import jest globally

Answer (score 16):

while essentially the same as the answer of Rupesh - you can expose `jest` globally without having to import it in each test file - by adding a setup-file to the jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
        "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    ]
}
```

then add this to `test-setup.js`:

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

global.jest = jest;
```

also in general ESM support for jest is improved by a `test` script in package.json as so:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --no-warnings --experimental-vm-modules $( [ -f ./node_modules/.bin/jest ] && echo ./node_modules/.bin/jest || which jest )"
},
```

Comment: This should be the excepted answer, instead of adding `jest` import to every test file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error on NextJS, and I found the answer here that solved my problem:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/jest-next-dynamic/issues/22#issuecomment-1030885706

So just remove the test from within the `pages` folder into a separate, e.g. `__test__` folder. This is a NextJS-specific use case though.

*UPDATE*:
Since Next introduced `app` folder for the new router, this is not an issue anymore, you can store the test files together with the components.

Answer (score 0):

just figured this out

inside of setup.global.js anything that uses the jest global MUST beinside of
the globalSetup function

```
import matchers from "some-jest-matcher" 

matchers() // jest not found errors

export default async function globalSetup() {
 matchers() // also jest not found errors
}
```

Comment: sorry i was wrong. even inside of globalSetup issues can happen