# TypeScript Jest imports with .js extension cause error: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've reached a dead end trying to fix this issue.
I am using the following TypeScript configuration:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2022",
        "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
        "target": "es2017",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "experimentalSpecifierResolution": true
    }
}
```

As you see the moduleResolution is set to **nodenext**, and because of that I have to explicitly add a file extension when importing, like this:  `import ServerError from '../models/Errors/ServerError.js';`. Otherwise, I get an error that the module was not found.

Everything is working fine, but when I launch my tests I get an error:  `Cannot find module '../models/Errors/ServerError.js' from '../src/services/usersService.ts'`. So basically jest is trying to find the file ServerError.js, but it does not exist, because all files have a .ts extension, so it should be ServerError.ts. If I try to change .js to .ts in my files I also will get an error.

I can't finish my task because of this problem, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to solve this problem after doing some research and updating my jest config file.

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
    transform: {
        '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            useESM: true
        }
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '(.+)\\.js': '$1'
    },
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts']
};
```

With this configuration, everything is working fine. I hope that it will help somebody.

Comment: I find out that configuring _ts-jest_ through globals property is outdated. Instead, you should remove 'ts-jest' from globals and write the following to the transform property: 
`transform: {'\\.[jt]sx?$': ['ts-jest', { useESM: true }] }`. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1057
I couldn't solve this when not using "ts-jest" though

Answer (score 10):

For me this did the trick:

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^(\\.\\.?\\/.+)\\.js$": "$1",
  },
```

(Adapted from https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1057#issuecomment-1441733977)

Comment: This is enough with the recommended transform from the ts-jest docs: `"^.+\\.tsx?$": ["ts-jest", ....]` .  It isn't needed to set `moduleFileExtensions` or `extensionsToTreatAsEsm`.

Answer (score 2):

I added only `moduleNameMapper` key in my case, this solved the issue for me. I've been using `ts-jest/presets/default-esm` preset.

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/default-esm",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "(.+)\\.js": "$1",
  },
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Additionally, in my jest test files themselves I needed to add a new import `import { jest } from '@jest/globals'` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65203348/470818 .  Though https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802002/470818 says there may be a way to do it without importing jest globally.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem with add a config `moduleFileExtensions` setting in `jest.config.json`;

```json
{
    ....
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "js"],
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by using jest-ts-webcompat-resolver npm package.

```
npm i jest-ts-webcompat-resolver -D
```

In your `jest.config.ts` add:

```
"resolver": "jest-ts-webcompat-resolver"
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was a mix of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816302/11365260) and the settings from [TS-Jest documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets#advanced).

```js
const { defaultsESM: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets');

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  ...tsjPreset,
moduleNameMapper: { '^(\\.|\\.\\.)\\/(.+)\\.js': '$1/$2' },

  // ....
```