# Testing extension method with ts-jest

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, luxon

I created an extension method for luxon's `DateTime` class:

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

declare module "luxon/src/datetime" {
  export interface DateTime {
    myFunction(month: number): DateTime;
  }
}

DateTime.prototype.quarterStart = function (month: number): DateTime {
  
  const result = DateTime.fromObject({
    day: 1,
    month: month,
    year: year,
  });

  return result;
};
```

The method implementation is not what's important, it will be something else.

Then on my tests I have:

```
describe("DateTime extensions", () => {
  it.each<number>([1,2,3,4])("call quarterStart  function", (month) => {
    const testDate = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2023, month: 5,day: 1 });

    const start = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2023, month: month, day: 1 });;
    const expected = testDate.quarterStart(month);
    expect(start).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

I don't get any errors if I try to build the code, but if run the tests it fails with this message:

> TypeError: testDate.quarterStart is not a function

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73735202/typescript-jest-imports-with-js-extension-cause-error-cannot-find-module) but nothing works.

I haven't been able to find any other info online.

Am I missing something on the extension side, jest config, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Test could not find your extension method at runtime.
You need to import 'luxon/src/datetime' into your test file.

```
import 'luxon/src/datetime';

describe("DateTime extensions", () => {
  it.each<number>([1,2,3,4])("call quarterStart  function", (month) => {
    const testDate = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2023, month: 5,day: 1 });

    const start = DateTime.fromObject({ year: 2023, month: month, day: 1 });;
    const expected = testDate.quarterStart(month);
    expect(start).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```