# How do I fix SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I have tried just about every single tutorial and approach to get Jest to recognize import statements. However, I cannot find a working solution in 2021.

Things I have tried:

- All of the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export) stack overflow post
- Jest's documentation page on this [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules)
- Babel's documentation page on configuring Jest [here](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation)

Here is my current layout. I have tried many others as well.

Error message:

```sh
  
    /Users/lukeanglin/Desktop/Convene/frontend/convene/node_modules/expo-secure-store/build/SecureStore.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { UnavailabilityError } from 'expo-modules-core';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { LOGIN_URL } from '../config/globals';
      2 | import { LOG } from '../config/logger-conf';
    > 3 | import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
        | ^
      4 | import axios from 'axios';
      5 | export async function login(email, password) {
      6 |   // Returns true if login succeeds and false on fail (also logs error message)
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { LOGIN_URL } from '../config/globals';
      2 | import { LOG } from '../config/logger-conf';
    > 3 | import { SecureStore } from 'expo-secure-store';
        | ^
```

babel.config.json

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

package.json

```json
// stuff here 
"type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
},
// stuff here
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Create an expo project
- Install Jest and babel, and expo-secure-store
- Attempt to import SecureStore
- Right a function doing something with the file that attempts to import SecureStore

Additionally, the entire content of the file that causes the error on the import is here:

login.js

```js
import { LOGIN_URL } from '../config/globals';
import { LOG } from '../config/logger-conf';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import axios from 'axios';
export async function login(email, password) {
  // Returns true if login succeeds and false on fail (also logs error message)
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
      username: email,
      password: password
    });
    // Save the token
    const token = response['data']['token']
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    LOG.error(
      'Error on GET request to login for authentication OR error on storing token with SecureStore: \n' +
        error
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

and the test tests the function `login`.

Anyone with working configurations of Jest and Babel to make ES6 modules like SecureStore functional (and import statements, exports, etc.) who can help me, I will greatly appreciate you!

**TLDR** - How do I fix `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` using Jest?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655153/12417483

Comment: You can't use commonjs import like you used in your login.js file. Change it to es6 import

Comment: @nlta if you see my package.json i actually already have that

Comment: @DerEchteKroate could you specify what you mean by changing it to an es6 import?

Comment: @Luke Anglin look at your login.js file. You are clearly importing axios on line 4 with the commonjs method. Change it to es6 import

Comment: I just tried that. I still get the error on line 3 with the import SecureStore

Comment: This issue has been raised in the [project repo](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5026) and there is not yet a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I learned this **is not a problem with Babel or Jest config**, but rather this is limited to the *SecureStore* item itself. This module seems to pose problems specifically, as other imports work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).