Problems to test and run programs in TypeScript
I have been making an app in TypeScript with Express. Now I want to make unit tests (a bit late, I know) and found this problem:

To run the tests, imports inside of .ts files need not to have the file extension .js
To compile the code tested, imports inside of .ts files need to have the file extension .js

Is there some config that I'm missing?
jest.config.js:
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
// module.exports = {
//   preset: 'ts-jest',
//   testEnvironment: 'node',
// };

export default {
  preset:"ts-jest",
  testEnvironment:"node",
  testMatch: [
    '**/*.test.ts' // Solo ejecutar archivos .test.js
  ]
}

tsconfig.json:
{
   "compilerOptions":{
    "target": "es2016", 
    "module": "Node16",
    "rootDir": "./src", 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": false,    
    "noEmitOnError": false, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
    }
}

What I did:

Eliminating the .js extension inside .ts files
Changing the moduleResolution value to "bundle", given what I read here, but the compiler said that moduleResolution couldn't have that value


What error do you get? Did you tried exporting the configuration with module.exports = in .js or renaming the jest.config.js to jest.config.mjs ?

Does your package.json file contain a type property? If so. what is the value?

@rveerd  Yes, it's "type": "module"

@Teneff  When the file extension isn't present I can run tests but the compiler throws this error: '''Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in ECMAScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext''' but I can't change de moduleResolution value without breaking the app, it seems to accepts only those values.

When the file extension is present ''' Cannot find module '../services/UserService.js' from 'src/tests/UserRepository.test.ts'
  1 | // UserService.test.ts
> 2 | import UserService from '../services/UserService.js';''' I know that that file doesn't exists yet, so it's logic


@MarianaArona try renaming the jest.config.js to jest.config.mjs

type "module" means es modules. So possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export. Myself, I'd recommend doing all of the following: 1) change *.ts files to *.mts files. 2) change all imports to both avoid default exports and use specific paths as your error states, e.g., import { UserService } from '../services/UserService.mjs';. And then use the settings from that link. Also, it's always useful to include specific errors to each configuration change you tried in the question. And welcome to SO!

I found the solution.
Seems like you HAVE TO deactivate the option "module": "ES2022" in the tsconfig file in order to let you execute files without file extension (while keeping the "module"... in package.json.
This also creates another problem, you can't import packages installed by npm anymore... so you also have to use this option in the tsconfig file "moduleResolution": "node"
Resumen nivel 5 taringuero:
//"module": "ES2022" "moduleResolution": "node" 
