# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word while requiring another es5 module

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-5

I am creating a node application which requires a local package **es5_pkg** (written in ES5).

**es5_pkg** is a separate project which i need to include in my node application and This is using babel transpiler.

I am getting error

```
import _ from 'lodash'; SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Don't know what to do with. Not able to resolve this issue. Help me resolve this.

#### node application index.js

```
var npmPackage = require('es5_pkg'); // This package is in ES5
```

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "es5_pkg": "file:../es5_pkg"
 },
```

Comment: I believe you need to transpile (e.g. using babel or similar) if you're using `import` since it is not supported natively by node yet.

Comment: Updated the question. Can you please suggest something which is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for other questions/answers?  Sounds like your babel is not setup correctly.

Perhaps this will help:

[Unexpected reserved word 'import' when using babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710319/unexpected-reserved-word-import-when-using-babel)